# Issue with Microsoft Access

Tags: c#, c++, ms-access

We have 2 legacy systems - One in `C++` and other in `C#`  that connect to the same `access database`. The `access database` is not password protected and we use the following connection string to connect to the databases

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Persist Security Info=False ;Data Source= AlarmHistory.mdb
```

`C#` application polls a table in the database every 10 seconds. Once in while , the `C#` application crashes with the error message -

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user.
```

The log analysis revealed that both the applications are not accessing the database simultaneously ... Any  idea on what could cause such a situation... Please Help

Comment: Instead of checking the application log use a tool like ProcMon that really checks whether a file is in use by another user. An application may report that it finished working with a database but still keep file handles open.

Answer (score -1):

They might not be accessing the database at exactly the same time, but that error message indicates that they (or something else) is accessing the lock file at the same time. Is the poll opening and closing the connection each time? You could move the open and close to outside the timer so that the connection is opened and remains open for the life of the application.

Comment: The file won't be locked, it is only briefly exclusively locked during creation. So by keeping the connection open, the locking file won't keep being created and destroyed.